# なかで after past tense verb

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

The narrator says that he has a life flying around the world as a pilot, and then says:

> そんなふうに生きてきた**なかで**、僕はいわゆる有能な人たちと、ずいぶんつきあってきた。
>   *Living in this way*,  I have come to associate with many people who are supposedly capable people.

I don't think I've got the first clause correct, because I think I could translate 'Living in this way,...' simply as 「そんなふうに生きて、...」

My other guess is that it means "among the people who are living like this..." , but wouldn't that be そんなふうに生きてきた**人の**なかで? It seems a bit far-fetched to omit 人.

So, I don't know what なかで is doing here and I've also failed to get the auxiliary verb きた into my translation.

Comment: Is it possible that なか is actually hiragana for 仲, relationship?

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone I doubt it. I am pretty sure it denotes the span of time during which he has been living, or '中.'

Comment: Is it really 生きてきた not 生きていた? What is the relation between English and Japanese? Is it your translation? Which way?

Comment: @macraf: We say そんなふうに生きてきた not そんなふうに生きていた in this context.

Comment: @mackygoo I was asking primarily what the context was.

Comment: @macraf: たぶん「文脈」と "context" との意味が微妙に違うのだと思います。改めて、日本語でコメントを書きます。「この文脈では、”そんなふうに生きてきた” と言いますが ”そんなふうに生きていた" とは言いません。」　なお、「この文脈」とは、「そんなふうに生きてきた」を含めて後続する「僕はいわゆる有能な人たちと、ずいぶんつきあってきた。」で表現される文全体を通じて理解することができる意味であって、必ずしもこの文の前後の文は無くても十分に分かります。

Comment: @macraf 生き**てきた** (have lived... (up to now)) so つきあっ**てきた** (have associated with... (up to now)). 生きて**い**たなかで... would mean "while I was living this way (in the past, but not now anymore)". 「生きていた・つきあっていた」と違って、「生きてきた・つきあってきた」は、今も続いている感じがするでしょう？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the usage of 中 here is perhaps similar to that of the following sentences.

> 今まで生きてきた**中**で、一番幸せです。I am happier than I have ever been in my life.
>
> 本日はお忙しい**中**（お越し下さって）ありがとうございます。Thank you for coming today (even though you/you all are so busy).

As you can see, it can be used to denote not just a spatial center, but also a span of time or circumstances surrounding a person.

Jim Breen's JDIC also lists "**during; while**" as a definition of 中.

> 中 【なか】 (n) (1) inside; in; (2) among; within; (3) center (centre); middle; (4) during; while

Similarly,

> そんなふうに生きてきた**なか**で、僕はいわゆる有能な人たちと、ずいぶんつきあってきた。

Here, what the author means is "while in .. situation (of living this way).." or "while living this way.."

It may be difficult to comprehend at first, but it is not an uncommon pattern. You should be able to find plenty of other examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

質問者および回答者の提供する「なか/中」を含む文の「なか/中」の部分を別の表現に置き換えて「なか/中」の意味の理解に供したいと思います。

- そんなふうに生きてきた**なかで**、僕はいわゆる有能な人たちと、ずいぶんつきあってきた。
  そんなふうに生きてきた**過程で**、僕はいわゆる有能な人たちと、ずいぶんつきあってきた。
- 今まで生きてきた**中で**、一番幸せです。
  今まで生きてきた**時間の中で**または**境遇の中で**、一番幸せです。
- 本日はお忙しい**中**（お越し下さって）ありがとうございます。
  本日はお忙しい**状況/事情にも関わらず**（お越し下さって）ありがとうございます。